# TextInput from React Native does not show entered text

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement a simple iOS application with React Native. However, I got stuck with a problem with the `TextInput` element.

It works fine until I try the next steps:

1. Enter some long text (the text should be longer than the input itself)
2. Put the cursor to the beginning of the text
3. Try typing something.

I expect that after I type, say, *abc*, it will look like this:

[image]

However, by some reason, the result is like this:

[image]

I.e., *abc* is entered, however, the cursor stays at the initial (leftmost) position and the entered text is not visible. I have to move the cursor to the left myself to see the text. That is not expected behavior: I, as a user, feel that the input is broken and my text just is not entered at all.

I did not found any solution for the issue so far. Is it a bug of React Native or I just do something wrong?

Thank you.

#### Update #1

Created a [simple Expo project](https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/react-native-text-input-problem/App.js) to reproduce the issue.

#### Update #2

Looks like an issue of React Native. Reported [the issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22627) and implemented the workaround proposed by @HelmerBarcos (with `multiline={true}`).

Comment: I think your are making some mistake in the styles. It is the TextInput component from react-native itself? cCan you  please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @HelmerBarcos, thank you for the quick comment. I am going to prepare the smallest possible project that reproduces the issue and update the question with the link to it.

Comment: on Expo do you mean? it would be nice!

Comment: Just created the project to reproduce using Expo: https://github.com/yaskovdev/sandbox/blob/master/react-native-text-input-problem/App.js

Comment: Good question. I just found out I have the same issue in my app. Weird behaviour

Comment: hi, i'm facing the same issue, have you find a workoround to this problem ?

Comment: @NicolasDeTiesenhausen, I implemented the workaround that Helmer Barcos suggested in his comment: https://github.com/motivepick/motive-mobile-app/blob/master/app/components/common/UniversalInput.js, probably you could try the same approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not making proper use of the corresponding property or `props` of the TextInput Component. For a better understanding of their use, please read the official API documentation from React Native components in this case [TextInput Component Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput)

You need to use the  `placeholder` prop and it should works. It could be that there is another mistake on your StylesSheet.

I have created an [Expo example](https://snack.expo.io/@lui5778/dGV4dG) for you just for showing the correct way. You can add your own code there if you want to experiment with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the example! Unfortunately, the `placeholder` is not what I need. A user should have possibility to _edit_ earlier entered text using the text input. The placeholder does not give the user such possibility. As for the stylesheet, that is definitely not the cause (checked by commenting out all the stylesheets from my minimalistic example).

Comment: Try whit the `multiline={true}` prop it lets you edit the value and shows the new one correctly. I edit my Expo please take a look there

Comment: Thank you. Decided to implement the workaround you proposed (with `multiline={true}`). Updated my question.

Answer (score 4):

I faced same issue, and solved it by adding:

```
flex: 1
```

on text input style.

Answer (score 0):

you only need add: `selection={{ start: 0 }}`

```html
<TextInput
label={"My Label"}
value={"Your LOOOOONNG TEXT"}
selection={{ start: 0 }} //<- Only put this
/>
```